# What is the diffrence between "commit" and "newrev" in change-merged hook?

Tags: gerrit

I'm using following documentation: https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/HEAD/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md#change_merged which describes parameters passed to given hook.

At the moment I want to get commit message body based on commit that has been merged in `Gerrit`. Unfortunately there are two parameters which passing commit `SHA`, those are namely `--commit` and `--newrev`. I have also tried to print them out for single merged commit and value points to same commit (in my case both values are: `bd2b60cccc9fba84ac66aa161ac07008b4803575`)

I'm wondering which one should I use for my use case when I want to refer to commit that generated given instance of event that triggered the hook. Are there any case when those values can differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "newrev" is different from "commit" when a merge commit is generated for that commit when the change is submitted to the destination branch.

See more info [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-ci/+bug/929723) and [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=2785).

Comment: As a note I will point out that if you want to generate easily situation described above for testing purpose use `Merge Always` strategy. Then you can check out empirically which parameter you will be intrested in.